# Is there any other possiblitly to prove this point other than using 'extern' keyword :n3290 draft

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++11, scope

A point from ISO draft N3290 :
Unqualified Name Lookup :section 3.4.1, para 14:

> > If a variable member of a namespace is defined outside of the scope of its 
> >        namespace then any name that appears in the definition of the member 
> >        (after the declarator-id) is looked up as if the definition of the member
> >        occurred in its namespace.

ex:

```
namespace N {
   int i = 4;
   extern int j;
}
int i = 2;
int N::j = i;       // N::j == 4
```

Is there any other possiblitly to prove this point other than using 'extern' keyword

can u give some other examples ... other than extern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another example which doesn't use `extern` keyword:

```
//demo.cpp

int i = 100;
namespace N
{
    int i = 200;
    struct A
    {
        static int m;
    };
}

int N::A::m = i; //i is 100 or 200?

int main()
{
   cout << N::A::m << endl; //what will it print?
}
```

Output:

```
200
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/pRVAb

Comment: Your both examples will give linker errors if `namespace N` header file included in multiple .cpp files. So you have to end up using `extern` keyword for `int i;` :)

Comment: @iammilind: I added `demo.cpp` in the comment, to remove the possibility of linker error.

Comment: @iammilind: Since the `i`s are not part of the problem, you can always declare them as `const int i = ...;` and you avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't use `extern` yet it *more or less* proves the point. Note that it doesn't define *variable* outside the namespace, it instead defines *function* outside the namespace.

```
//demo.cpp

int i = 100;
namespace N
{
   int i = 200;
   struct X{};
   void f(const X&);

}

void N::f(const X&)
{
   cout << i << endl; //what will it print?
}

int main()
{
    N::X x;
    f(x); //use argument-dependent lookup (ADL) to find the function!
}
```

Output:

```
200
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/KCqUV

I added ADL to make it more interesting!

Comment: You posted twice. At first I was appalled at the blatant copying someone did, then I felt silly.

Comment: @GMan: This is a different answer. This is not a duplicate of my other answer.

Comment: You should probably combine them, then.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is regarding the definition of a **static member in class**.

```
// header
namespace N {
  const int i = 4;
  class A
  {
  public:
    static int m_i;
  };
}

// source file
int i = 2;
int N::A::m_i = i;  // N::A::m_i == 4

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cout << N::A::m_i << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This gives linker error if, `namespace N` included in multiple .cpp file. You have to make **extern** `int i;`.

Comment: To be picky, yes. But it's already defined in namespace scope as in OP's code. So I don't think that matters too much here regarding the topic we're discussing.

Answer (score 0):

```
// header.h
struct X { void bar () {} };
namespace N {
 struct X { void bar () {} };
 void foo(X *p = new X);
}

// implementation.cpp
#include"header.h"

N::foo(X* p) { p->bar(); } // N::X::bar() called
```

This example is without using `extern`. (though it's implied).

Comment: You think that `N::foo` is a "variable member of a namespace"?

Comment: @6502, not the `N::foo`; but applicable to all the variable data members inside `N::foo` :). OP has already given the extern variable example.

Comment: Then your answer is not relevant: -1

Comment: Still I see no "variable member of a namespace" here, you do?

Comment: @6502, you should see `foo(X* p = new X)`; where `X` is a variable; it can be `::X` or `N::X`.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think that the *variable* part is really important, the same behavior present in the opening quote for the definition of variables outside of its namespace exists for functions in the namespace. That being said, `X` in the above comment is not a variable, it is a *type*

Comment: @David, I know that the variable part is not important, but since I got downvote just because of that, I changed my code to satisfy it. And also, I meant the `new` object of `X` by referring to the `foo(...)`.

Comment: @David, I know that the variable part is not important, but since I got downvote just because of that, I changed my code to satisfy it. And also, I meant the `new` object of `X` by referring to the `foo(...)`.